# Get several rows of the same Table SQL Server 2008 in one record

Tags: sql-server

I have a table looking like this

```
UniqID   |Part             |Name
---------|-----------------|----------------------------------------------
1        |StickerForm      |C:\Muscateers\SummaryLabel.dotm
2        |InvoiceForm      |\\online-storage\secure\MMCC Invoice Layout.dotm
3        |RepairForm       |\\online-storage\secure\MMCC Repair Layout.dotm
4        |Receip Label     |\\online-storage\secure\ReceiptLabel.dotm
5        |InvoiceSavePath  |\\online-storage\secure\Invoices\
6        |RepairSavePath   |\\online-storage\secure\Repairs\
7        |ReportPrinter    |HP LaserJet P2050 Series PCL6
8        |ReceiptPrinter   |EPSON TM-T88IV Receipt
9        |StickerPrinter   |Brother QL-810W
```

I would like to retrieve the name column from UniqID 3,6,7 in 1 result i.e.

```
\\online-storage\secure\MMCC Repair Layout.dotm   \\online-storage\secure\Repairs\   HP LaserJet P2050 Series PCL6
```

Is that possible? If so could you show me a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Most answers was using `Coalesce` or similar and I didn't want that
I finally got what I wanted after 4 days of trying and trying

```
Create table #myrow 
    (eForm varchar(65) ,
     ePath varchar(65) ,
     ePrint varchar(65))

Create table #Temp 
    (   UniqID int, 
     Name Varchar(65))

Insert into #Temp
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT [Uniqid],[Name] FROM [dbo].[PathForms]
     where UniqID in (3,6,7))src 

Insert into #myrow
     SELECT * FROM #Temp
     PIVOT (MAX([Name]) FOR [UniqID] in ([3] , [6] , [7]  )) as pvt

Drop table #Temp

Select 
    eForm, ISNULL(ePath,'') as ePath ,ePrint from #myrow 

Drop table #myrow
```

Comment: So now what is the question ? Is that resolved or still want something ? If resolved then why you posted this question ?

Comment: However you are using `ISNULL` which does the same thing as `COALESCE` and in fact isn't ANSI standard whereas `COALESCE` is.

Comment: There is no question This is the answer to a question I asked about a week ago and most people misunderstood the Question and gave me answers with Coalesce. I wanted it to come back as one record and I got it.. I could not make any further comment to the original question, which is why I posted this